# Rasterizing a point layer without using an attribute field

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, rasterization, raster-conversion

I am following the "QGIS by Example" text book and a task requires that a point layer is rasterized using the following GDAL code

```
gdal_rasterize -l layer name -burn 1 -a_nodata 0 -te coordinates - tr 10 10 -ot Byte
```

This should provide a raster layer with the value of `1` for the point locations and `0` elsewhere within the coordinates provided. A tiff file is generated but doesn't show on the map canvas despite my styling attempts. I have tried all sorts of variations in the GDAL command and added an integer field set to `1` to the shapefile to use this but without success. This may not be relevant but I have used the book download file for the next exercise using the raster proximity tool but receive a message stating that the GDAL dataset can't be opened. Is there an issue with settings in QGIS - my version is 2.18.26

Comment: Perhaps add `-init 0` ?

Comment: I would suggest inspecting the output TIF to see what it has done - Zoom to Layer to see if extents are as expected. Check properties for min/max of raster bands, CRS, etc. You may also run the command omitting the -te parameter and it will default to the input extents.

Comment: But you will not be using that command literally so written, right?